# Need to Create a Table that has references another table and has variables

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, function, variables

I need to create a table that has the following features:

- An employee number that references the employee number on the employee table
- I need to add a salary field

  - the salary is based upon hire date which is also in the employee table
  - if employee is hired less then 3 years then salary would be 30k
  - less than 5 then it is 45 k
  - and 5-10 55 k more than 10 60 k
- it needs to have tax info where if the employee lived in Alaska, there is no tax otherwise tax by state
- this is also a field on the employee table
- the net pay is 90% if the person has no tax and 75 % if they have a tax
- pay date must be a future date
- check number must not be null or duplicate

Any help will be appreciated as I'm not sure where to begin. A UDF function?  Copy the employee table somehow and add the fields I need?

Answer (score 2):

<s>First, locate the period (.) key on your keyboard.  You will need it for this solution (as well as for posting future questions at Stackoverflow).</s>

To solve your problem you should create a VIEW that JOINs together your employee and tax info tables and includes calculated columns in the output to get determine the salary, tax status, and net pay.  I would attempt to give you an approximate version of the CREATE VIEW statement you need, but you've given no information about your table structures or column names.